# Using Recursion in JavaScript to shift Array elements to different positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I've yet to find a solution that is in JavaScript (a lot of Java and C++) using recursion, and not new/old index splicing. This is merely an exercise and I'm not great at recursion, so any assistance and a thorough explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
//given an array, shift all elements within the array forward 2 positions.
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] --> [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

My first line of thought was to use a placeholder of some sort but I'm not sure what to do with it exactly. This is what I have so far

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function shiftTwo (arr) {
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    let curr = arr[0];
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using recursion:

```js
function shiftArr(arr, n) { 
   if (n<=0) {
       return arr;
   } 
   else{  
       arr.unshift(arr.pop()); 
       return shiftArr(arr,n-1)
   }
}

//test:
console.log(shiftArr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],2));   // [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to recur on the number of spaces to move.  If it's 0, return the array intact (or possibly clone it with `arr.slice(0)`); otherwise, shift the last entry to the front and recur with one less.  The code might look like this:

```js
const shiftRight = (n, arr) =>
  n <= 0
    ? arr
    : shiftRight (n - 1, [...arr.slice(-1), ...arr.slice(0, -1)])
      

console .log (shiftRight (2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```